# Detect if any thing was written to the output ie. StdOUt

Tags: powershell, stdout

How do I detect if any thing was written to the Output stream ie. StdOut in the script's lifetime.

1. This has to be checked right before an *exit* from the Script so that only then - screen can be halted.
2. The output could have come from any source including external commands like `java.exe`

Preferably, without the overhead of a file to which output could have been redirect and checked for size.

Update: Native applications like java.exe may not use the standard streams for output. `Output-Default` Cmdlet does not work even in `Start-Transcribe`.

I am currently relying on the Error-Code `$?` to detect a failure of `java.exe` but of course this is *limited*.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would be much easier if the script was run as a background job.  Then all the ouput would be buffered and read using receive-job.